# How to split the numbers and characters in to two strings in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I want to split the string like FG12344 in to FG and 12344 using Objective C. I don't how to do this, please help me in this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the characters:

```
NSString *characters = [@"FG12344" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
```

For the numbers:

```
NSString *numbers = [@"FG12344" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: what is the number is a floating point number? i.e. 1234.56ft.

Comment: it should be [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] and I think that would take care of integer and floating point numbers.

Comment: Yes @cspam, [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] would let you with the number, either integer or float.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **NSPredicate** for similar cases.